# Laravel 5.2 Storing data in another Database after Registration

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Im using the default registration and log in form of laravel. What i want to happen is how do i store a data after the user successfully register. I tried doing this but its not storing any data in the Time_tracker table and there is no any error occured. Can some one help me?

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Time_tracker;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'maintenance';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'company' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'telephone' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);

}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'telephone' => $data['telephone'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user = new Time_tracker;

    $user->current_time = 0;
    $user->purchase_time = 0;
    $user->status = 'not_paid';
    $user->user_id = $id;

    $user->save();

    }
}
```

Comment: are you config your `DB` inside the `.env` file? and this is the not best way to insert data into the table.

Comment: @RimonKhan yea. there is no problem in that part, because in my other Controller, It is saving in the DB table properly. My problem is in this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the created user that's why the code below it isn't running, you should remove return and place it at the end in this way:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([   // <------ Removed 'return' from the front of this line
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'telephone' => $data['telephone'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $time_tracker = new Time_tracker();

    $time_tracker->current_time = 0;
    $time_tracker->purchase_time = 0;
    $time_tracker->status = 'not_paid';
    $time_tracker->user_id = $user->id; // <----- This would be '$user->id' instead of '$id'

    $time_tracker->save();

    return $user; // <----- 'return' added at the end of the method
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is an error. ErrorException in AuthController.php line 84:
Creating default object from empty value.

Comment: @Ace - If it works for you please upvote/accept this answer as it motivates me to solve more questions like this..